# How can you use h2 in memory data in a Spring Boot API?

Tags: spring-boot, h2, swagger-ui

We are building a new API using Spring-Boot. For testing, we want to use the h2 in memory data base to test our API.

**How do you setup h2 db so Spring-boot can use that data during that session?**

Ideal situation, I can call GET and retrieve everything that was created in my h2 db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test folder, create a Defaultdatasourceconfig class, that will have all the necessary beans (like DSbean, TXManager bean etc). For the new DriverManagerDataSource() method, pass the necessary datasource properties (create a properties class with the below fields and annotate them with @Value and the property names), add those properties to your application-test.properties file

```
db.hsql.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
db.hsql.username=sa
db.hsql.password=sa
db.hsql.driver.name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.platform=hsqldb
```

If you want to load specific tables related only for your usecase, add this to the prperties files spring.datasource.schema=classpath:abc.sql and add abc.sql under the same folder as application-test.prpoerties.
So, when you run the test, when the context builds, it will use hsql db as Primary db, loads table by executing the sql and uses this db.
you will need to add hsql driver in your classpath.
Same can be done with h2

Comment: Thank you for responding! I figured it out, I needed to change my application.yml a little big and add a @NoArgConstructor to make the code happy